# Linux - how to set group permissions for new files in advance

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to tell Linux that each file that is created in a certain directory should have g+w in addition to the default permissions.

How do I say that? I need the sticky bit of that directory, dont I ?
(The directory already has drwsrwsr-x which I was hoping the new files would inherit, but obviously they dont...)

Comment: Read about [`umask`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html).

Comment: thanks, hmmm, to me this looks like a ssystem-wide setting? I only want this to happen in a certain folder. Why I need this: It is a folder for log files, where both apache and also a locally running php script (started by upstart) need to write log files into. Sometimes I clear this folder, so the files are re-created, and then it happens that the permissions are too strict. I put a "chmod g+w *.log" in the upstart script, but some of the logs are created later at certain events in the application, so this does not fully work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mechanisms related to permissions manipulations:

- `umask` allows you to *disable* permission bits *per application*. It doesn't allow neither enabling permissions nor doing it per directory. It's also not a global setting. It is a per-process attribute that is inherited from parent process. E.g. you can set its default value in init script, but programs (especially daemons) may overwrite their `umask`.
- `sticky bit` restricts directory access so that files in that directory may only be unlinked or renamed by root or the directory owner or the file owner.
- `setgit bit` on directory forces any new files created within that directory to have their group set to the same group that's set on the directory. It allows to overwrite group owner, but not permissions.
- `bsdgroups` or `grpid` mount option enables `setgit bit` behaviour for all directories, even if `setgit bit` is not set.
- `ACL` (access control lists) allows you to set per-user and per-group permissions for a directory or file. They are also inherited from parent directory when new file is created in that directory. However, `ACL` permissions are masked against traditional POSIX permissions, which are set by file creator and its `umask`, so you can't inherit more permissions than allowed by file creator.

All of these mechanisms except `umask` are linux-specific. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/getting-new-files-to-inherit-group-permissions-on-linux) for some details about `setgit bit` and `ACLs`.

I guess non of these is a direct solution for you problem. What you can do:

- Configure programs that create those files to create them with sufficient permissions. E.g., if they create them (or can be configured so) with permissions `0777`, setting `umask` to `000` should be enough. See @KasunRathnayaka's answer.
- If it's not an option, you can use [`bindfs`](http://bindfs.org/) tool with `--create-with-perms` and related options. It allows to mount a directory to another directory and overwrite permissions and user/group owners when files are created or modified. See [manual page](http://bindfs.org/docs/bindfs.1.html).

Comment: Thank you for this overview - since I am not using Linux regularly, this is what will help me to choose a decent approach!

Answer (score 0):

you can change umask in you linuxbox. as what you want.

```
Umask   Created Files       Created Directories
-------------------------------------------------------------
000     666 (rw-rw-rw-)     777     (rwxrwxrwx)
002     664 (rw-rw-r--)     775     (rwxrwxr-x)
022     644 (rw-r--r--)     755     (rwxr-xr-x)
027     640 (rw-r-----)     750     (rwxr-x---)
077     600 (rw-------)     700     (rwx------)
277     400 (r--------)     500     (r-x------)
```

eg:

```
root@kasunr:/usr/share/nginx/html/tt# umask 
0022
root@kasunr:/usr/share/nginx/html/tt# umask 0027
root@kasunr:/usr/share/nginx/html/tt# mkdir yy
root@kasunr:/usr/share/nginx/html/tt# ls
yy
root@kasunr:/usr/share/nginx/html/tt# ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 ජූලි   22 15:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 ජූලි   22 15:19 ..
drwxr-x--- 2 root root 4096 ජූලි   22 15:20 yy
```